# MySQL longtext filed concat big data chunks

Tags: php, mysql

I need to add a 30MB content (which in future can be bigger) to a longtext MySQL filed, but without changing the `max_packet_size` to more than 16M.

So I split the content to 10MB chunks thinking I can `concat` them, but I hit an unknown for me limit and when adding the second 10MB chunk the filed get reset to its default value (NULL). I was able to figure out that the problem is not caused by the query of the second chunk, executing the first query twice lead to the same result. I split the content to 1.5MB chunks, properly importing 12 of them and the 13th NULLed the filed. Then I increased the `max_packet_size` to 32 and all chunks were imported.

My questions are:

Is `max_packet_size` the cause for this issue or there is something else I don't see and increasing the value is fixing the other problem as well?

Is there a PHP solution to this issue, if it's not caused by `max_packet_size`?

Here is my query:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `result`=CONCAT(IFNULL(`result`, ''), 'huge string') WHERE `id`=1
```

I'm adding the PHP tag in case there is a PHP solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/packet-too-large.html):

> ```
>      Packet Too Large
>      A communication packet is a single SQL statement sent to the MySQL server, a single 
> row that is sent to the client, or a binary log event sent from a source replication
> server to a replica.
> ```

That said there is no PHP solution for your problem and the reason `concat` chuncks does not work is because when you `concat` strings a new string is created with the summed size of both strings and eventually when the summed size is bigger than the `max_packet_size` you will get an error.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure `concat` works this way, but it obviously does